How to remove (authentication) fingerprints?
I suddenly lost the ability to authenticate via fingerprints in Windows Hello. It used to work, there were no particular changes and the rest of Windows Hello works (face recognition mostly).
I wanted to set it up again via Settings, the setup starts but tells me that the fingerprint I am trying to add already exists.
How can I remove these fingerprints that seem to be present somewhere but cannot be deleted via Settings (at least I did not find any - in particular the "Remove" button is not present, only "Setup").
In desperation, I managed to reset Windows Hello entirely (via certutil.exe -deleteHelloContainer" IIRC) but the fingerprints were still "present". I had to recreate the face recognition but failed with fingerprints like before. I also removed laptop-specific software (Lenovo), just in case. And rebooted, deleted in device manager, etc - the typical attempts to fix stuff.
My question: how to remove, at a low level, fingerprints stored by Windows 11
EDIT: I tried to add a brand new fingerprint hoping that it may "reset" the status and open the "Remove" functionality but something is really wrong because even then I get

